# how to maximize $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y-2}{xy}$?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, fractions, maxima-minima, convexity-inequality

How to maximize $f(x,y)=\frac{x+y-2}{xy}$ where $x,y \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$?

It seems that maximum will occur when $(x,y)=(1,n)$ or $(n,1).$

Comment: What holds at the maximum? **Hint:** $f_x(x,y) = 0 $ and $f_y(x,y) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(1,1)=0$ and $f(1,2)=f(2,1)=\frac {1}{2}$

Otherwise,
$$\begin{align}
f(x,y)&=\frac{x+y-2}{xy}\\
&=\frac {1}{y} +\frac {1}{x} - \frac {2}{xy}\\
&=\frac {1}{y} \left(1-\frac {1}{x}\right) +\frac {1}{x}\left(1-\frac {1}{y}\right)\\
&\le\frac {1}{2} \left(1-\frac {1}{x}\right) +\frac {1}{2}\left(1-\frac {1}{y}\right)\\
&\le1-\frac {1}{n}
\end{align}$$

Note that $$f(1,n)= 1-\frac {1}{n}$$

Thus the maximum is $ 1-\frac {1}{n}$ which is achieved at $(1,n)$.

Comment: How to insure that maximum is not achieved at any other values?

Comment: Because $\frac {1}{y} (1-\frac {1}{x}) +\frac {1}{x}(1-\frac {1}{y})\le 1- \frac {1}{n}$ for $x,y    \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}    $.

Comment: yes, maximum value is $1-1/n$ and is attained at $(1,n)$ but there may be other values of $(x,y)$ for which maximum is attained too. My point is how to discard that case?

Comment: @Sry You can take care of other cases by turning the inequalities into strict inequalities; e.g., when $x < n$, we have $1 - \frac1x < 1-\frac1n$.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1):

Let $M$ be a maximal value.

Thus, $$Mxy-x-y+2\geq0,$$ which is a linear inequality of $x$ and of $y$,
which says that it's enough to check this inequality for the extreme values of $x$ and $y$: $$(x.y)\in\{(1,1),(n,n),(1,n),(n,1)\},$$
which gives $$M\in\left\{0,\frac{2(n-1)}{n^2},\frac{n-1}{n}\right\},$$
which gives that $\frac{n-1}{n}$ is a maximal value.

Comment: It involves the term $xy$. Is it still linear?

Comment: The term $xy$ is a linear of $x$ and it's a linear of $y$.